# Trouble syncing file-based templates to database using MSM and config bootstrap

Tags: expressionengine

Had started my typical EE build (using a bootstrapped config) for a client when they announced they wanted another additional site using the MSM module (le sigh).

So added the MSM module, I commented out the `$config['site_url']` and `$config['cp_url']` and set those in index.php instead using `$assign_to_config`.

That's when I discovered [this bug](http://expressionengine.com/bug_tracker/bug/18262) where MSM config file settings are not recognized, which is a pain but I can work around it. However, I noticed that when I created the secondary site, it wouldn't recognise my custom location for add-ons and so I had to add that to index.php as well to `$assign_to_config['third_party_path'] = "../assets/third_party/";`.

Then I discovered that when I create or modify a template file, it won't automatically sync and so I need to manually do that each time which is a real PITA.

Why would my templates not be syncing to the database? Is this related to the MSM config bug?

Comment: Wait what? Your question is a little confusing - could you perhaps boil it down to a set of steps to reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: Another area to investigate is whether you're logging in via one control panel URL or one per site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't tried bootstrapping the third party path yet, I've definitely been able to bootstrap the template path for MSM sites... What bootstrap method are you using?

Are your sites on subdomains or subfolders?  I've only had experience with subfolders so perhaps that makes a difference (although it shouldn't).

Could you maybe walk through in a bit more detail what's happening?  Your first site (site_id = 1) templates sync automatically from filesystem edits, but your second site does not?  Yet if you go to CP > Design > Synchronize Templates, that works?

The $assign_to_config portion of MSM setup is definitely a weakspot when it comes to bootstrapping... I wonder if we need to work up an additional bootstrap for MSM+CP environment, where it looks at the cp cookie ($_COOKIE['exp_cp_last_site_id']), and sets values based on that.

Comment: I built a 20 site MSM install last year and would be happy to contribute to this.

Comment: yeah that's exactly it "Your first site (site_id = 1) templates sync automatically from filesystem edits, but your second site does not? Yet if you go to CP > Design > Synchronize Templates, that works?"

I'm wondering if the issue is the single domain cp rather than using admin.php to to mask the CP access.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful if you let us know which bootstrap you are using. For example, if you look at [this bootstrap](https://gist.github.com/3862276) the `site_url` and `cp_url` are set using the `HTTP_HOST` server variable, so this shouldn't clash with your MSM install (and multiple domains) at all.

Perhaps you could try using that boostrap file instead, and see if it fixes your issue with template syncing?

Finally, if you're going to use the EE template manager, you don't really need to store templates as files. Conversely, if you want to save templates as files, it's probably much easier editing them using Sublime Text or another editor, rather than the clunky built-in editor (which is really only useful for small/simple changes).

Comment: This is the bootstrap https://gist.github.com/869022

I won't be using the EE template manager, haven't done that since my early EE days.

The secondary site is a subdomain but within a folder of the primary site but the cp is accessed via the primary domain.